# Maven: separate "Build" from "Run" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working with my first Maven project in Eclipse. I want Maven to build (run configuration is of type Maven Build) my jar file and everything additional to `${project.basedir}/build`. I configure my `pom.xml` as follows.

```
<build>     
  <directory>${project.basedir}/build</directory>
```

Now I have the problem that when I want to Run (*not* build, so the run configuration is of type Java Application) then the `${project.basedir}/build` directory is being used as current working path.

How to I separate directories for build and run in Maven (Eclipse Plug-in)?

Comment: Why do you need to have separate them? You use the same build system?

Comment: I just want to, personal preference. It seems cleaner to me.